# Get a collection of an attribute by linq

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file.

```
<BOOK bnumber="1" bname="Book">
    <CHP cnumber="1">
        <VER vnumber="1">This is the sentence 1.</VER>
        <VER vnumber="2">This is the sentence 2.</VER>
        <VER vnumber="3">This is the sentence 3.</VER>
   </CHP>
   <CHP cnumber="2">
        <VER vnumber="1">Hello World 1.</VER>
        <VER vnumber="2">Hello World 2.</VER>
        <VER vnumber="3">Hello World 3.</VER>
        <VER vnumber="4">Hello World 4.</VER>
   </CHP>
   <!--MANY: Thousand records-->
</BOOK>
```

I want to ge the attribure "cnumber". The result:

```
Chapter={"CHP 1";"CHP 2",....};
```

My uncomplected code:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Book.xml");
        var temp = xdoc.Descendants("CHP").Where(x => x.Attribute("cnumber").Value != "0");
```

Thanks.

Comment: What isn't working? I'm not exactly understanding what your expectations are.

Comment: By the way, your sample data are malformed. You start tags with `<VER>` and end them with `</Sentence>`

Comment: Just corrected it. Thanks for reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you could probably use:

```
var chapters = xdoc.Descendants("CHP")
                   .Select(x => "CHP " + x.Attribute("cnumber").Value)
                   .ToList();
```

It's not clear why you need a `Where` clause at all - certainly none of the *sample* data you've given has a `cnumber` of 0, or an absent `cnumber`. If you need to take that into account, you should say so explicitly.

(Do you really need the "CHP " part to start with, btw? Why not just have a `List<int>`?)

Comment: Yes, I only need "CHP" part to start with.